# Android NDK Shared Object Undefined Reference Error

Tags: android-ndk, shared-libraries, webrtc

I have been running into a weird problem while trying to compile code for Android. My code is interfacing with two third party libraries (libcurl and WebRTC) and when it gets to the linking phase (linking against compiled shared object files) it reports that there are undefined references to functions within WebRTC but the libcurl functions are fine. Examples of the undefined errors that I am getting are:

```
WS.cpp:208: error: undefined reference to 'buzz::XmlElement::AddAttr(buzz::QName const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)'

ThirdPartyLibs/WebRTC/src/third_party/android_tools/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/memory:1636: error: undefined reference to 'buzz::QN_MESSAGE'
```

When I run `nm -C` on the WebRTC library file and then `grep` the results for the functions, the functions are clearly shown to exist and be defined (in the text section).

```
nm -C Android/libs/armv7/libWebRTC.so | grep "AddAttr"
000753e5 t buzz::XmlElement::AddAttr(buzz::QName const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)
0007541d t buzz::XmlElement::AddAttr(buzz::QName const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)

nm -C kino/Android/libs/armv7/libWebRTC.so | grep "QN_MESSAGE"
000bfd10 d buzz::QN_MESSAGE
```

When I say that I am linking against a compiled WebRTC shared library I should note that the shared library is being compiled using either ninja compiled static libraries or object files. I am compiling using the following:

```
GCC_armv7=$projectDir/ThirdPartyLibs/WebRTC/src/third_party/android_tools/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc

OBJS_armv7="…list of static libraries or object files…”

LDFLAGS="-lc -ldl -lm -fPIC 
--sysroot=$projectDir/ThirdPartyLibs/WebRTC/src/third_party/android_tools/ndk/platforms/android-16/arch-arm 
-L$projectDir/ThirdPartyLibs/WebRTC/src/third_party/android_tools/ndk/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib/"

$GCC_armv7 -v -shared $LDFLAGS -o libWebRTC.so -Wl,-soname=webrtc $OBJS_armv7
```

When I link my code directly against the ninja compiled static library files, or the ninja compiled object files, I do not get the same errors. Since it works, it would be nice to just link against either of these. However, I have been told by Java Android developers that although Java accepts static libraries, Android does not. And I cannot imagine that either Java or Android would compile against object files.

I have also had to forcibly reference the files in the LOCAL_LDLIBS parameter in the Android.mk file instead of using the LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES or the LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES parameter.

When I tried using the former method, ndk-build would never seem to find the appropriate library files. Instead it seemed to use the system version of the libcurl and libopenssl libraries.

Just as a sanity check, I ran the same `nm | grep` command on the object files and static library files and compared them to the results for the shared object file. Below is a comparison of the `nm –C | grep` results between the static / object files and the compiled so file.

```
static / object -
00000001 T buzz::XmlElement::AddAttr(buzz::QName const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)

shared object -
000753e5 t buzz::XmlElement::AddAttr(buzz::QName const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)
```

From what I have been able to gather on the output of `nm`, there is no difference between “T” and “t”, but I don’t understand why it would change between the two sets.

I should note that the gcc (or g++) compiler being used is the specific gcc / g++ binary for the respective architecture provided by the WebRTC download (`commit hash: aad6780e5c25b1622904ef83659461706f6a25db`). For the ndk-build(ing) I am also using the ndk-build binary that comes with the WebRTC download (`src/chromium/src/third_party/android_tools/ndk/ndk-build`).

My question: What am I doing wrong such that linking against object files will compile an ndk-build Android.mk file, but linking against a shared object file will fail with some of the functions being defined and the other not being defined?

**UPDATE:** I just tried compiling the so file using ndk-build and an Android.mk file instead of gcc / g++, and I am getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way around this problem. Instead of trying to build a separate shared object file for WebRTC, I went back down the route of directly linking against the compiled object files. Doing this forced ndk-build to include those objects in the compiled shared object file for my code. Thus, my final library .so file was significantly larger than planned. But that does not matter, since it is holding all of the WebRTC libraries we are using. For those of you with a similar problem, be aware that the compiled library files in the `./libs/<arch>/` folder are stripped down of symbols. So if you `nm | grep` them, you will get an error. If you need to do any sort of sanity checking with that command, use the compiled libraries in `./obj/local/<arch>` instead.

I am not going accept this answer in case someone else comes along and is able to actually address the problem without a work around.